# Get teams where the user is member, using Bitbucket API

Tags: node.js, bitbucket, bitbucket-api

How can I get a JSON object with teams (organizations) where the user is member?

I am searching in [documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/) and in [Bitbucket REST API Console](http://restbrowser.bitbucket.org/).

Basically I need the correspondent for `orgs.getFromUser` [function from Github API](http://ajaxorg.github.io/node-github/#orgs.prototype.getFromUser) where I pass the username after authenticating.

Comment: You link to the generic Atlassian documentation, but is it safe to assume you've looked through the specific [REST API docs](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Using+the+Bitbucket+REST+APIs#UsingtheBitbucketRESTAPIs-SupportedEndpointsandtheirResources)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "User Endpoint" for API 1.0

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/user+Endpoint

The call your looking for is: `https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/user/privileges`

You need to call this with user authenticated:

```
curl -u "USER_NAME:USER_PASSWORD" https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/user/privileges
```

This will return a list of teams:

```
{u'teams': {u'team1': u'admin', u'team2': u'admin'}}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for [this endpoint](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/groups+Endpoint#groupsEndpoint-GETalistofgroups).

You provide the `accountname` and authenticate for it, and `GET /1.0/groups/:accountname/`. It will return a list of objects displayed on the documentation page.

Comment: You are correct. I didn't found it because on Bitbucket they are called "teams", on Github "organizations" and I see that here in API "groups". Why do I receive "Bad request" when I enter on [this](https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/groups) url? If I go [here](https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/user/repositories/) I can see my repositories, after auth. It also throws "Bad request" in REST API console.

Comment: I have no clue why that throws a bad request in your browser on visiting `/groups` and not on `/user/repositories`. That might be something to point out to Atlassian in a support request.

Comment: I will accept this answer when the problem will be solved. If you find something helpful please post. Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't matter to me whether you accept my answer or not but did you contact Atlassian about the issue?

Comment: `/user/privileges` returns the correct output. Also, `/groups/myusername` returns an empty array.